# Stop Visual Studio from starting the currently selected/opened HTML page when debugging

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

If I have a c# web application project, such as a MVC project, and I create/add a .HTML file, and I am editing the .HTML file, when I start the debugger it does not start normally, instead it starts with the .HTML file I am currently editing.  I would prefer it start normally like a MVC project, using the default route.

Is this configurable?  Can I tell VS that even if the current context is a .HTML page, that it should ignore that fact, and start as if there were no file currently in context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click on your Web Project:

```
Properties -> Web -> Start Action
```

You can set it to a specific page, rather than the (annoyingly) default Current Page.

[image: VS2013]

Comment: Thanks Jonesy - that was exactly it.  Ya know, I have probably seen that screen a thousand times, and never really stopped to see what it all meant.  Been driving me crazy for years.  What an epiphany.